# How to parse unicode character to xml format standard

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some problem such as. When I call webservice and Webservice return Dataset and output as following:

```
"\u003cNewDataSet\u003e\r\n \u003cTable\u003e\r\n \u003clSellLocID\u003e81\u003c/lSellLocID\u003e\r\n \u003cColumn1\u003e81\u003c/Column1\u003e\r\n \u003cszDescription\u003eAKL Airside sdda\u003c/szDescription\u003e\r\n \u003cbPreOrder\u003e0\u003c/bPreOrder\u003e\r\n \u003c/Table\u003e\r\n \u003cTable\u003e\r\n \u003clSellLocID\u003e82\u003c/lSellLocID\u003e\r\n \u003cColumn1\u003e82\u003c/Column1\u003e\r\n \u003cszDescription\u003eAKL Landsite\u003c/szDescription\u003e\r\n \u003cbPreOrder\u003e0\u003c/bPreOrder\u003e\r\n \u003c/Table\u003e\r\n \u003cTable\u003e\r\n \u003clSellLocID\u003e85\u003c/lSellLocID\u003e\r\n \u003cColumn1\u003e85\u003c/Column1\u003e\r\n \u003cszDescription\u003eAKL Arrival\u003c/szDescription\u003e\r\n \u003cbPreOrder\u003e0\u003c/bPreOrder\u003e\r\n \u003c/Table\u003e\r\n \u003cTable\u003e\r\n \u003clSellLocID\u003e886\u003c/lSellLocID\u003e\r\n \u003cColumn1\u003e886\u003c/Column1\u003e\r\n \u003cszDescription\u003e886-PreOrder\u003c/szDescription\u003e\r\n \u003cbPreOrder\u003e-1\u003c/bPreOrder\u003e\r\n \u003c/Table\u003e\r\n\u003c/NewDataSet\u003e"
```

I want it output XML format.

Comment: Are you *sure* the API is returning JSON escaped XML?!

Answer (score 1):

If this is the actual character data you have got, then you need to do some string replacements. Assuming the string is the value of a variable `s`, then you can do this:

```
s = s.replace(/\\u003c/gi,"<").replace(/\\u003e/gi,">").replace(/\\r\\n/g, "\n");
```